# Excel: combine OFFSET with CELL

Tags: excel, offset

Is it generally possible to combine OFFSET with CELL in Excel?

I want to have a offset with a dynamic reference.

Formula which produces "We found a problem with this formula":

```
=OFFSET(CELL("address";INDEX(Example!U:U;MATCH(VLOOKUP($A3;Example!$D:$U;18;0);Example!U:U)));1;1)
```

When only testing

```
=CELL("address";INDEX(Example!U:U;MATCH(VLOOKUP($A3;Example!$D:$U;18;0);Example!U:U)))
```

The result is the reference to this cell, so this part is working.

OFFSET requires the Reference as first argument. But somehow, it is not working.

Comment: CELL("address" returns a string, but you should be able to use OFFSET(INDEX(

Comment: ah, thanks, that's it! I was not aware CELL() actually returns a string which is somehow not considered as reference.

Comment: actually, you don't need OFFSET too. Just INDEX and MATCH should be enough. OFFSET is volatile function and is recalculated even when not needed https://trumpexcel.com/excel-volatile-formulas/